# Matching the nth occurrence of a single character in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble finding any regex which actually matches what I need, despite how easy this request seemed when I started out. Hoping to get help here.

An early mistake in our code is sending dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:SSS`. This is not valid ISO, as the milliseconds are proceeded by a colon, not a period.

I wanted a quick regex to use in conjunction with JS .replace() to match the third colon `:` and replace it with a period `.` As I said, this sounded pretty basic -- but I have found nothing that works, and no other places where the suggested fix for a similar problem has worked in my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/^((?:[^:]*:){2}[^:]*):(.*)$/`; `(?:[^:]*:){2}` matches up to the second colon and `^((?:[^:]*:){2}[^:]*)` matches the string from the beginning of the string until the third colon; `(.*)$` matches everything after the third colon; Capture what is before the third colon and what is after, reformat the string with back reference:

```js
console.log("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:SSS".replace(/^((?:[^:]*:){2}[^:]*):(.*)$/, "$1.$2"))
```

Or a simpler one for this specific case, replace the last colon with `.`:

```js
console.log("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:SSS".replace(/:(?=[^:]*$)/, "."))
```